# How to check is Jenkins Job workspace is in use

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Let's say I have 2 jobs

- JobA
- JobB

JobA and JobB use the same workspace. I don't want JobA to run when JobB is running through checking if the workspace is in use.
How can a check if a given Jenkins workspace is in use by a Job?

FYI - this is just a simple scenario. There are more complex scenarios to handle which is why I need it to work this way.

**Expected Result:**

Let's say Workspace is "c:\workspace"

JobB is running in "c:\workspace".

JobA is attempts to start, JobA checks and sees workspace is in use. Pipeline aborts. (or even better if possible, the pipeline waits for JobB to finish and then runs)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to use [Lockable Resource Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/), which allows you to acquire locks on resources and wait until they are released to perform certain pipeline operations.

First, create a lock called `workspaceLock`, and the following are two sample pipelines, which utilize the lock.

**JobA**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { string(name: 'foo', defaultValue: '', description: '') }
    options {
        lock ('workspaceLock')
    }
    stages {
        stage("StageA") {
            steps {
                echo "Do Something in JObA"        
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**JobB**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { string(name: 'foo', defaultValue: '', description: '') }
    options {
        lock ('workspaceLock')
    }
    stages {
        stage("StageB") {
            steps {
                echo "Do Something in JObB"        
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```